# Omnet++ UDP and beacon sending (inet/examples/wireless/lan80211)

Tags: udp, omnet++, inet, beacon

i have a problem with sending udp datagrams between host's connected to one AccessPoint. Below i show my ned and omnetpp.ini files i use example from inet/examples/wireless/lan80211.
All i want to do is to send beacon frames with some interval and also send UDP datagrams between hosts.

.ned file :

```
package inet.examples.wireless.lan80211;

import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.nodes.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.world.radio.ChannelControl;


network Lan80211
{
parameters:
    int numHosts;
submodules:
    host[numHosts]: WirelessHost {
        @display("r=,,#707070");

        wlan[*].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtSTASimplified";
    }
    ap: AccessPoint {
        @display("p=213,174;r=,,#707070");

        wlan[*].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAP";
    }
    channelControl: ChannelControl {
        numChannels = 2;
        @display("p=61,46");
    }
    configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        config=xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x'       netmask='255.255.0.0'/></config>");
        @display("p=140,50");
    }
}
```

Omnetpp.ini file:

```
[General]
network = Lan80211
#cmdenv-output-file = omnetpp.log
#debug-on-errors = true
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 600m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 400m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

**.debug = true
**.coreDebug = false
**.channelNumber = 1

# channel physical parameters
*.channelControl.carrierFrequency = 2.4GHz
*.channelControl.pMax = 2.0mW
*.channelControl.sat = -110dBm
*.channelControl.alpha = 2


# access point
**.ap.wlan[*].mac.address = "10:00:00:00:00:00" #1=*
**.host[*].**.mgmt.accessPointAddress = "10:00:00:00:00:00"
**.mgmt.frameCapacity = 15
**.mgmt.beaconInterval = 0.04s


# UDP app (host[0] pinged by others)

**.numUdpApps = 2
**.udpApp[1].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPEchoApp"
**.udpApp[1].localPort = 1000
#**.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "host[0]"





#*Host[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.host[0].udpApp[1].destPort = 1000
**.host[1].udpApp[1].destPort = 1000
**.host[0].udpApp[1].destAddresses = "host[1]"
**.host[1].udpApp[1].destAddresses = "host[0]"
**.host[*].udpApp[1].sendInterval = 10ms


# nic settings
**.wlan*.bitrate = 2Mbps

**.mac.address = "auto"
**.mac.maxQueueSize = 14
**.mac.rtsThresholdBytes = 3000B
**.wlan[*].mac.retryLimit = 7
**.wlan[*].mac.cwMinData = 7
**.wlan[*].mac.cwMinBroadcast = 31

**.radio.transmitterPower = 2.0mW
**.radio.carrierFrequency = 2.4GHz
**.radio.thermalNoise = -110dBm
**.radio.sensitivity = -85dBm
**.radio.pathLossAlpha = 2
**.radio.snirThreshold = 4dB


[Config Ping1]
description = "host1 pinging host0"
*.numHosts = 2

[Config Ping2] # __interactive__
description = "n hosts"
```

I find that when i change the line

```
wlan[*].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAP";
```

in .ned file the datagrams arived from one host to another but then beacon's sending doesn't work.

Also, i get some info from command window during simulation when udp datagram is pending:

** Event #320  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[0].udpApp[1] (UDPBasicApp, id=15), on selfmsg `sendTimer' (cMessage, id=10)
** Event #321  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[1].udpApp[1] (UDPBasicApp, id=35), on selfmsg`sendTimer' (cMessage, id=21)
** Event #322  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[0].udp (UDP, id=16), on `UDPBasicAppData-2' (cPacket, id=304)
Sending app packet UDPBasicAppData-2 over IPv4.
** Event #323  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[1].udp (UDP, id=36), on`UDPBasicAppData-2' (cPacket, id=305)
Sending app packet UDPBasicAppData-2 over IPv4.
** Event #324  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[0].networkLayer.ip (IPv4, id=18), on `UDPBasicAppData-2' (UDPPacket, id=306)
Sending datagram`UDPBasicAppData-2' with dest=145.236.0.2
Routing datagram `UDPBasicAppData-2' with dest=145.236.0.2: output interface is wlan0, next-hop address: <unspec>
no next-hop address, using destination address 145.236.0.2 (proxy ARP)
Sending out packet to interface wlan0
** Event #325  T=0.02  Lan80211.host[1].networkLayer.ip (IPv4, id=38), on`UDPBasicAppData-2' (UDPPacket, id=307)
Sending datagram `UDPBasicAppData-2' with dest=145.236.0.1
Routing datagram`UDPBasicAppData-2' with dest=145.236.0.1: output interface is wlan0, next-hop address: 
no next-hop address, using destination address 145.236.0.1 (proxy ARP)
Sending out packet to interface wlan0

Any advices?

Thanks,
MB